# Pandas DataFrame Link To Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, traversal

If I had a dataframe like this:

| #bunch more columns | name | name1 | name2 etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| baz |  | jim | bob |
| --- |  | tom | sam |
| baz |  | jack | kyle |

(Please note there are 22 columns for name)

And a dictionary like this:

```
{jim: 10, tom: 5, jack: 5, bob: 18, sam: 12, kyle: 6}
```

What would be the quickest way of creating some sort of intermediate df with the values of each dict replacing the names. like

```
name name1 ...
10   18    ...
5    12    ...
5    6     ...
```

Edit: clarification

Every item in various name columns within dataframe is stored within 'name_dict'. I want to replace all these items with their respective value within name_dict. So if I have a column containing "Bob" and, within name_dict, Bob's value is 43, I want to replace "Bob" with 43 within the column.

Pseudo:

```
 dict = {bob: 12, jim: 43, tom: 23}
df =            
| bob  |
| jim  |
| tom  |

>>> replace columns in df with value from dict
>>> | 12 |
>>> | 43 |
>>> | 23 |
```

Comment: `dataframe.applymap(name_dict)`?

Comment: you mean DataFrame with index name and value numbers?

Comment: I clarified your expected output. It started out pretty vague, so please correct if I misinterpreted your question (which could be clarified)

Comment: `df.replace(name_dict)`.

Comment: I clarified what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested:

```
>>> df
   name name1 name2
0  jack  jack   bob
1   sam   bob  jack
2   bob   sam   sam
3  kyle   tom   jim

>>> name_dict
{'jim': 10, 'tom': 5, 'jack': 5, 'bob': 18, 'sam': 12, 'kyle': 6}

>>> df.replace(name_dict)
   name  name1  name2
0     5      5     18
1    12     18      5
2    18     12     12
3     6      5     10
```